# How to quit webview in replit?

Tags: bash, web, replit

I have created a Nix repl for my project and it starts a web server in the background using `nohup python3 -m http.server &`. It works fine when I log in to my account and execute it, but when I log out, it doesn't run the web server in the background, but instead, shows the web preview. I tried using the `embed=1&output=1` parameters, but it still doesn't hide the preview. Please help. Here is the link to my repl: https://replit.com/@Dark-cobra/WAFER

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you talking about logging out of your website or logging out of the server terminal?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Sorry for the hasty and poorly written post, let me shed some light on the topic when we start a webserver or create a website using replit, automatically, a web preview opens up. It shows a preview of the website we made. So the issue is, when anybody executes my repl without logging in, the web preview window takes over the whole screen, so is there any way to quit or close the web preview window?